# LinqPad execute without filling in every parameter

Tags: c#, sql, linqpad

I have an SQL Procedure with a bunch of optional parameters (17 of them).

How do I execute a procedure with only specifying the parameters I need using C# or Linq or Lamba? (no SQL since I can do that already).

[image: example of a procedure]

Comment: It isn't clear how you intend to call the SP (unless that is the crux of your question?).  Are you using raw ADO.NET? Dapper on top of ADO.NET? EF? There are a myriad of ways to actually call a stored procedure.

Comment: You don't, at least not with LINQPad's autogenerated wrappers. It would have had to generate the method with default values (`int? size = default`), it doesn't, so you can't. You are of course still free to use a plain old `SqlCommand` to call the procedure.

Comment: so are you suggesting that I would need to say size=default,page=default,totalpages=default,etc......

Comment: If you insist on using LINQPad's methods, then yes, you can do that. But that's much worse than using `SqlCommand`, because it will break if the parameter list ever changes. With `SqlCommand` you would only pass the parameters you actually use.

Comment: What do you mean "no SQL" - you want a way of calling the sproc that uses no sql, or you literally mean [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL)

Comment: i dont literally mean NoSQL. I mean't not using SQL Syntax. I am using an SQL Server database. I am just new to Linqpad. Trying to get the hang of it. I can use SQL Management Studio but thought I should try some of these features and it's a little overwhelming